# Selectively getting items from the same classname in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im using selenium to scrape a liquor store page. I'm trying to get name,volume,country of origin and the price of a product. The product is contained in catalog_product_item_cont class.

```
items = Driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"catalog_product_item_cont")
print(str(len(items)) + " items found")
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

This bit of code gives me just what i want as seen on the screenshot 1[list of items that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5gBE.png), but on the bottom of the website there is some sorta news/articles section, items in which are contained under the same class name, which leaves me with a lot of useless thrash (screenshot 2)[useless thrash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a23lH.png)

My question is, how do i differentiate between these two and select only the products?
[The product that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzAt5.png)
[Useless thrash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukQOK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think one way can be to see if each product has a unique id, and use that instead of the class to select the item with selenium.
- Another way can just be postprocessing your list, so that you delete everything that comes after the last element that follows a certain pattern (name,volume,country of origin and the price).